# Passing data from controller to master view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel and I've a large amount of `index.blade.php` pages that extends a `master.blade.php` page, now the `master` need some data like the list of menu items.

When I want to see the list of `Aircraft` I've this route:

```
Route::get('aircrafts', 'AircraftsController@index');
```

and this is the method `AircraftsController@index`:

```
public function index(){
    $aircrafts = Aircraft::all();
    $menus = Menu::all();
    return view('aircrafts.index', compact('menus', 'aircrafts'));
}
```

How you can see I must to pass `$menus` to each view in each controller, and if in some moment the `master` require some other data I'm forced to edit every single controller...

Is there some more smart way to pass data to the master?

I would like to avoid to retrieve the interested data directly inside the view...

Answer (score 2):

in your AppServiceProvider add `use View;`

```
public function boot()
{
  View::composer('*', function($view){
    $view->with('aircrafts', Aircraft::all());
    $view->with('menus', Menu::all());
});
}
```

after that usage is same. Like `@foreach($menus as $foo)`

Comment: please comment if you encounter an error. I am using this method all of my project.

Answer (score 0):

If data requires in all views then you can try `view()->share('menus', Menu::all())` in service provider, Otherwise `View::composer()` is right option for this.